# Flask write test cases to which skip a function inside a api

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, pytest

my view.py file

> To achieve unit testing, I want to skip some functions which updates to db or have a api call          third party.I want to skip one decorator and one function

`````
    from flask import Blueprint
    from .decorators import dec1, dec2
    from xxxx.apis.v1.decorators import my_func

    test_bp = Blueprint('test', __name__, url_prefix='/test')
    from flask import jsonify



    @dec1
    @dec2 
    def hello():
        status_code = my_func()
    return jsonify({"message": "hello world"}), status_code
    
    XXXX.add_url_rule('/hello/', 'hello', hello)````
my test.py file
> But this test function is calling the my_func
> What am I doing wrong here??
`````

```
import pytest
from xxxx.wsgi import app
import unittest.mock
from xxxx.apis.v1.decorators import my_func

@pytest.fixture
def client():
   return app.test_client()


def test_hello_v1(client):
    with unittest.mock.patch('xxxx.apis.v1.decorators.my_func') as mocked_my_func:
        mocked_my_func.return_value = 200
    result = my_func()
    print(result)
    assert result == 200  # Check the HTTP status code
    assert not mocked_my_func.called  # Assert that my_func was not called
```